# sql injection challenge(preg_match)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

```
<?php 
include 'db.php';
$password = $_GET['password'];

 if(preg_match('/(\')|(\>)|(\-)|(    )|(\|\|)|(\<)|(!)|(or)|(not)|(from)|
            (where)|(\*)|(=)|( )|(like)|(if)|(50000)/i', $password) == 0)
    {
         $q = "select * from table where name='jon' and 
          secret=".$password." and belong_famaly=1";
        mysqli_query($conn, $q);
        if ($res = mysqli_query($conn, $q))
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res))
            {
                die($flag);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I need to Pass the SQL QUERY and get the flag(SQL Injection).

I need help I dont know what to do.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to pass the SQL QUERY and get the flag.

Comment: Whybdo you think you need a quote?

Comment: Why do you do the preg_match? Do you try do add some security here? In that case you should bind the parameter instead of passing it to the sql string: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: i want to pass the security

Comment: `50000` is a very... odd thing to want to filter out... Just use prepared queries, seriously.

Comment: This seems like a game, or puzzle, or something like that.  You're asking how to defeat a regex that is trying (in a very misguided way) to prevent a sql injection exploit.  Please be truthful about your motivation and intentions.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you're right, playing with strings is not the right approach.  But, if you wondered... I suspect the `50000` is someone's idea of a way to prevent a technique they've heard of, but don't fully understand -- a query that is designed to defeat a naive keyword filter by sending something like `union/*!50000select*/`, which a server of version 5.00.00 or higher would parse as something closer to `union<space>select<space>`.  Of course, just using `/*!40101*/` or one of hundreds of other values works right around that.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it is a challange, i am not hacking some one. can you more explain about the 5000 or just send link about it

Comment: I didn't say you were hacking anyone.  But you are not asking for help with a programming problem, either.  Stack Overflow is not an appropriate place to ask us to help you play a game, beat a challenge, win a contest, do your homework, etc.

Comment: `/*!50000*/` is an example of a [magic comment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html).  When a comment begins with `/*!xyyzz` it is treated as a comment only by servers running MySQL Server with a version prior to x.yy.zz.  For the listed version and later, what is inside the comment block is executed as though the comment block were not there.  Examine the "comments" in any file created by `mysqldump` to see how this is used to make dump files backwards compatible with versions of MySQL Server that are older than the machine from which the dump was created.